# Can't seem to get a minecart to move

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft 1.8.  I placed a powered rail on the floor of a room in my basement and a button to activate it.  I place the minecart, press the button and the cart doesn't move.  If I do the same thing outside, it works like a charm.  What gives?

Comment: A screenshot (or two) helps tremendously with these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to:

**Have a solid block before the first rail block..**
This is so that the minecart has something to clip into (and thus move due to "you're [the Minecart is] inside a block").
Another way to 'clip' the minecart to move is to stand in it, as it has clipping onto the player, like most (all) mobs.

#### OR

**Hop in it, and move it yourself.**
Simply go into the minecart and face in the direction the rail is facing. The hold W.
W and S allows you slowly move the Minecart forward/backward, whether it is to go to the next powered rail, or travelling the entire distance (very slowly) by holding down W.

---

Minecarts will only be sped up by powered rails if it is ALREADY MOVING. A stationary Minecart will have no effect from the powered rail (it'll stay still).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a solid block behind the minecart for the powered rail to start it moving. Put the block at the end of the track, and your minecart will move away from the block when you push the button.

Answer (score 0):

Like aytimothy said in his answer, either move yourself when in the cart or have block behind the powered rail for a nudge.
If that does not work, check if the sides of the rail or cleared from blocks. I've experienced some blockage that myself, so maybe that helps.